# Rabbitmq java client consumer handleDelivery method does not get called

Tags: java, rabbitmq, messaging

This is a very contrived example of a rabbitmq app which is both producer and consumer of messages in one single main method. The problem is the code inside overridden handleDelivery method never gets executed. I use Rabbitmq dashboard and see the queue fills up and consumes. And the line in handleConsumeOk gets printed.
Since I am new to rabbitmq I'm wondering if I have done something fundamentally wrong or I just got the idea of "Called when a basic.deliver is received for this consumer" wrong.

```java
public class RabbitMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TimeoutException, InterruptedException {
        Connection connection = Utils.getConnection("test");
        String payload = "hello world!";
        try (Channel channel = connection.createChannel()){
            channel.exchangeDeclare("sampleExchange", BuiltinExchangeType.TOPIC, true);
            channel.basicPublish("sampleExchange", "testKey", null, payload.getBytes());
        }

        System.out.println("Consume...");

        try (Channel channel = connection.createChannel()){
            channel.exchangeDeclare("sampleExchange", BuiltinExchangeType.TOPIC, true);
            channel.queueDeclare("testQueue", true, false, false, null);
            channel.queueBind("testQueue", "sampleExchange", "testKey");

            Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel){
                @Override
                public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
                    String message = new String(body);
                    System.out.println("Received: " + message);
                }

                @Override
                public void handleConsumeOk(String consumerTag) {
                    System.out.println("handled consume ok");
                }
            };

            Thread.sleep(2000);

            channel.basicConsume("testQueue", true, consumer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consuming happens on another thread. When I ran the code with IntelliJ idea debugger the code works. By adding some idle time to the main thread (e.g. Thread.sleep(1000) the consuming thread had time to finish its job. I am not sure but it seems consumer thread was a daemon thread and got killed after the main thread terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You publish the message to the exchnage before any queue is bound to it. RabbitMQ will discard any message it can't route to a queue.

Do

```java
channel.queueDeclare("testQueue", true, false, false, null);
channel.queueBind("testQueue", "sampleExchange", "testKey");
```

before you call `channel.basicPublish`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I changed the code as you said. Still I see through the management console that the message is published to the queue and get consumed. Even the code inside handleConsumeOk methods gets executed. Only handleDelivery method is skipped, even when I publish a message from console.